# Webview from html page retrived from sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, webview, android-sqlite

I know how to load html file from assets for a web view but I have more than 50 html files so I need to save all the files in sq lite externally using any software like sq lite browser and put that db file in assets folder to load web view from specific html file whenever needed

Answer (score 0):

it makes no difference.. if you store the HTML contents as do as what you have said - you have to write lot of additional code and may end up having no advantage. Instead, you can copy the the html files directly from assets to required folder and later load it in webview. Name the html files appropriately to load the right one.

Comment: Yeah but if my apk was decompiled all the html files can be seen very easily that is the problem so my friends suggested to keep all the files in sqlite for security issue.do u agree with my thought ??if I am wrong please guide me